# boost text serialization version (15 vs 18)

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, version

I have a custom class containing only a `std::map<std::string, int>`.
I'm trying to serialize that using boost::serialization.

I create an object with the data {"foor":13} (this is the map in my custom object).
Boost serializes that as

```
22 serialization::archive 15 22 serialization::archive 15 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 4 foor 13
```

So far, so good (?).

Now, I take the same source (with few adaptations), I compile as wasm instead of x86. 
The same object is now serialized as

```
22 serialization::archive 18 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 4 foor 13
```

So, for some reasons, in one case, Boost chooses to use version 15 of the archive while in the other case, it chooses version 18.
(obviously, unserialization of the x86-generated does not work in the wasm program)

How can I "force" Boost to use version 15 of the archive ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first serialized sample looks to be
invalid alltogether.

Secondly, let's check that the `15` and or `18` are the
archive version numbers:

```
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    unsigned v;
    {
        boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(std::cout);
        v = oa.get_library_version();
    }

    std::cout << "# get_library_version() -> " << v << "\n";
}
```

Prints ([see live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/94e07fd6fd06dc89))

```
22 serialization::archive 17
# get_library_version() -> 17
```

So, yes, that look accurate

Since they are hardcoded in the archive implementation, you'll have to use the corresponding Boost library version on both sides.

Relevant doc snippet:

> `get_library_version()`
>
> Returns an unsigned integer containing the current version number of the
>   serialization library. This number will be incremented each time the library
>   is altered in such a way that serialization could be altered for some type.
>   For example, suppose the type used for a count of collection members is
>   changed. The code that loads collections might be conditioned on the library
>   version to make sure that libraries created by previous versions of the
>   library can still be read.

Comment: Thanks a lot for `get_library_version` that I didn't found by myself. At the end of the day, it appears that, when linking during the "wasm" build of my program, I was referring to an other version of Boost than when linking for x86. I cleanly recompiled boost for x86 and wasm, then I adapter my CMakeList.txt files. Solved.

Comment: Cool. Do you have more information on how to compile for WASM? I last time I tried it it was pretty hard to accomplish for nontrivial code. A link will do obviously. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The tricky point was to build `Boost::serialization` for wasm and x86.

Clone boost, enter the cloned directory.

### wasm

I ended up with this line (patchwork of many researches on the web; I'm not even sure of the meaning/usefulness of each argument)

```
./b2 toolset=emscripten link=static variant=release threading=single --prefix=build_wasm --build-dir=build_wasm runtime-like=static serialization
```

### x86

```
./bootstrap.sh --prefix=build_x86
./b2
```

### next

At this point, we have two separated directories `build_wasm` and `build_x86` to link to.

At this point, I do not remember how I managed to get the file `libboost_serialization.bc`.

### cmake

In my `CMakeLists.txt`, the key lines are:

```
set(BoostWasm_DIR "/absolute/path/to/build_wasm")
set(BoostWasm_emm "${BoostWasm_DIR}/boost/bin.v2/libs/serialization/build/emscripten-1.39.13/release/link-static/visibility-hidden")

include_directories(${BoostWasm_DIR}/include)

file(GLOB boost_js "${BoostWasm_emm}/libboost_serialization.bc")
target_link_libraries( write_normalized ${boost_js} )
```

Since it is a work related project, I do not have a link to a full working example.

### build

```
emcmake cmake .
emmake make
```